# What is the maximum printing size for 12 Megapixels camera

Tags: printing, megapixels

The recommendation for printing images seems to be they should be printed at 300 dpi, so if I have a 12 Megapixel images in 4:3 format that would limit me to 12.5" x 10".

My question is if I have a really good lens and the image is totally in focus even when zoomed in to its pixels limit does that allow me to print at larger size or is the 12.5" x 10" limit the max size if image totally in focus.

Comment: The question referred to is good but it doesn't really answer my second question.

Comment: In that case, I suggest editing this question (and especially the title) to focus on that, and we can reopen it.

Comment: The "recomendation" is specificly for offset comerecial print at 150 lpi. This is a technical. You can go lower resolution like 150 ppi or inclusive 100 ppi and you won't notice the pixels at let's say 50 cm. This is 2x-3x times (9x actually) the size.

Answer (score 0):

You can print your images as big as you wish (which means lower dpi if pixel resolution of an image remains the same). But keep in mind that lower dpi means pixelized pictures when you look at them from a distance shorter that X (X depending on dpi and your eyesight).

Comment: The larger you make the image (or blow up a cropped section), the more easy it is to notice the pixels. It depends on how you'll use the print: a poster viewed across the room, or a frame print that will be examined closely.

Comment: okay understood so what would be the limit if viewing from 0.5m and 1.0m away